# Problem with displaying list thumbnail list in jqmobile

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

Hello I have a problem with displaying  thumbnail list in jqmobile.

If I tried>

```
      <li> 

      <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" /> 

      <h3><a href="index.html">Broken Bells</a></h3> 

      <p>Broken Bells</p> 

      </li>
```

Is everything O.K and looks it like>

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html

But if I try generate it dynamically via

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {

//Hide .gif loader image if data are succesully fetched
   // $('#load').fadeOut();

    $(xml).find("SHOPITEM").each(function () {

   $("ul").append("<li><img width=\"80px\" src=\""+$(this).find('IMGURL').text()+"\"/><h3><a href=\""+$(this).find('URL').text()+"\">"+$(this).find('PRODUCT').text()+"</a></h3><p>"+$(this).find('PRICE_VAT').text()+"</p></li>");


    });



}
```

I got items displayed, but content is not formated correctly.

Where can be problem please?

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 2):

You probably have already solved this by now, but if not, and for the sake of others who may have the same problem, I'll post this potential solution:

It's very likely that your CSS is not being applied to the DOM Elements (HTML) being generated and inserted into the DOM by your AJAX function.  Without working on it, I would suspect you may have to apply your CSS inline with the HTML being inserted to it will take affect.

I've run into a similar problem with HTML inserted via AJAX and trying to apply new javascript functionality to it.  jQuery came up with a solution for that called the "live()" function, but I'm not sure jQuery has a built function to apply CSS in the same way.

So a line like this:

```
.append('<li>This text is red</li>');
```

would become:

```
.append('<li style="blue">This text is blue</li>');
```

Rick

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to refresh the listview in javascript to get the formatting:

From http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html:
`$('#mylist').listview('refresh');`